# Unpacked operator in Selenium explicit wait

Tags: python, selenium

In my code I faced an issue, when I try to use an unpacking operator in an explicit wait, there is a problem: "Can't use starred expression here"

```
self.xpath = (locator, string)
WebDriverWait(self.sin.get_driver(),wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((*self.xpath)))
```

In this case is locator something like By.XPATH, and string - "//div[]//..." - xpath of an element on a page.

Can such problem be solved? Or is it impossible to use starred impressions in the explicit wait anyway?

Comment: Quick thing, looks like you have one too many parenthesis on your second line, it should be `WebDriverWait(self.sin.get_driver(),wait).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(*self.xpath))`

Comment: No, I have tried to launch code without additional parenthesis, but does not work. Now working it looks like: until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[1]")))

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium `EC.presence_of_element_located(())` method is expecting to receive a [By](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class object.
It is not intended to iterate over any kind of iteratable like list, tuple  etc.